# Is there a plan to merge Ubuntu and Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I heard that Ubuntu was going for full convergence, which means, as far as I can tell, running basically the same operating system across phones, tablets, PC's and TV's, by 14.04. Those plans are delayed, and now we have separate Ubuntu and Ubuntu Touch. Still, Mark Shuttleworth is [talking about convergence](http://www.pcpro.co.uk/news/interviews/386080/mark-shuttleworth-interview-taking-ubuntu-beyond-desktops), so I guess the plan is the same.

Did I get it right; is merging Ubuntu and Ubuntu Touch actually in the plans for some later date?

I would like to be able to run Ubuntu on ARM [Nexus 7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nexus_7_(2013_version)) and Ubuntu Touch on x86 [Surface Pro 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Surface_Pro_2), at some point in the future, even if not anytime soon.

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu Touch (Unity8 on Mir) is coming to the desktop (see Ubuntu-desktop-next iso).

At the moment it is not really functional on desktop or at least not as functional as Ubuntu with Unity7 on X.org is.

Unity8 on Mir will be default on Ubuntu desktop by 16.04 according to Canonical. Then the convergence will be completed.

Comment: What's the story now that 16.04 is out? It doesn't look good as far as I can tell.